# Stata- Is there a way to store data like Python's dictionary or a hash map?

Tags: stata

Is there a way to store information in Stata similar to a dictionary in Python or a hash map in other languages?

I am iterating through variable lists that are appended with _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7 ... _18 to delineate sections, and I want to sum the number of times the letters "DK" appear in each variable in each section.  Right now I have 18 for loops, with each loop iterating through a different section, saving the 'sum' of the total number of DK's in a new variable called DK_1sum, DK_2sum, and then I later produce graphs of that data.

I'm wondering if there is a way to turn all this into a large For loop, and just append the data to a dictionary/array such that the data looks like:

```
{s1Sum, 25 
s2Sum, 56 ...
s18Sum, 101}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be stored in a Stata matrix, a Mata matrix or just ordinary Stata variables.

```
 gen count = . 
 gen which = _n 
 qui forval j = 1/18 { 
     scalar found = 0 
     foreach v of var *_`j' { 
             count if strpos(`v', "DK") 
             scalar found = scalar(found) + r(N) 
     }
     replace count = scalar(found) in `j' 
 } 
 list which count in 1/18
```

For variation, here is a Stata matrix approach.

```
 matrix count = J(18,1,.) 
 qui forval j = 1/18 { 
     scalar found = 0 
     foreach v of var *_`j' { 
             count if strpos(`v', "DK") 
             scalar found = scalar(found) + r(N) 
     }
     matrix count[`j', 1] = scalar(found) 
 } 
 matrix list count
```

Comment: Brilliant.  I will try this and get back to you.  Had not seen scalars before.

Comment: I added a `which` variable. Otherwise which value is which could be scrambled by later sorting of the data.

Comment: Is there a substantive difference in the efficiency between the two approaches?  Which will run faster?

Comment: A wild guess is that there will be little difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about efficiency you could consider the associative array capabilities of Mata.

```
* associate Y with X
local yvalue "Y"
mata : H = asarray_create()
mata : asarray(H, "X", st_local("yvalue"))
* available in Mata
mata : asarray(H, "X")
* available in Stata
mata : st_local("xvalue", asarray(H, "X"))
di "`xvalue'"
```